# How to read csv with schema in pyspark

Tags: csv, pyspark

I know how to read a csv with pyspark, but I'm having a lot of problems to load it with the correct format. My csv has 3 columns, where the first and the second are strings, but the third is a list of dicts. I'm not being able to load this last column.

I tried with

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("_id", StringType()),
    StructField("text", StringType()),
    StructField("links", ArrayType(elementType=MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
])
```

but it's raising an error. With Inferschema neither it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `inferSchema="true"`. If it causes problems, read everything as string, and then you can use `ast.literal_eval()` from `ast` package to convert the `str` to `dict`.

You use this function:

```
def read_csv_spark(spark, file_path):

    """
    :param spark: SparkSession or SQLContext
    :param file_path: Path to the file
    :return: Spark Dataframe
    """
    df = (
        spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .options(header="true", inferSchema="true")
        .load(file_path)
    )
    return df
```